# How do we write $f(x+2)$ in terms of $f(x)$?

Tags: functions

$$f : R^+ \rightarrow R^+$$

$$f(x)  = \dfrac{x}{x+1} $$

How do we write $f(x+2)$ in terms of $f(x)$? This is a general question that I wondered how to algebraically write it.

Regards

Comment: Literally divide $\frac{f(x+2)}{f(x)}$ and you will get what you want.

Comment: One way to do it is $f(x+2) = \frac{x+2}{x+3} \times \frac{x+1}{x} \times f(x)$. It's not really clear what you're looking for.

Comment: If I get you right, you want a product/sum independent of x as a factor but only as an argument, because, as in my first comment, it would be obvious.

Comment: Something like $f(x+2) = f(f^{-1}(f(x))+2) = \frac{f(x)-2}{2f(x)-3}$???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't quite tell, but I think you're looking for a function $g$ so that

$$g(f(x))=f(x+2).$$

To do this, we find $f^{-1}(y)$ first. If $f(x)=y$, then

$$\frac{x}{x+1}=y\implies x=y(x+1)\implies y=x(1-y)\implies x=\frac{y}{1-y}.$$

So, if $f(x)=y$, then

$$f(x+2)=\frac{x+2}{x+3}=\frac{\frac{y}{1-y}+2}{\frac{y}{1-y}+3}=\frac{y+2(1-y)}{y+3(1-y)}=\frac{2-y}{3-2y}.$$

So, your answer is

$$f(x+2)=\frac{2-f(x)}{3-2f(x)}.$$

Comment: Oh...I was too slow typing the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

A more general method:

$$f(x) = \frac{x}{x+1}$$
$$f(x)(x+1) = x$$
$$(f(x)-1)x=-f(x)$$
$$x=\frac{f(x)}{1-f(x)}$$
Hence,
$$f(x+2)=\frac{x+2}{x+3}=\frac{\frac{f(x)}{1-f(x)}+2}{\frac{f(x)}{1-f(x)}+3}=\frac{f(x)+2(1-f(x))}{f(x)+3(1-f(x))}=\frac{2-f(x)}{3-2f(x)}$$

Note: I usually think that this can easily go wrong, so you may want to do some checking: $f(1+2)=\frac{3}{4}$ by the original expression, and indeed $f(1+2)=\frac{2-f(1)}{3-2f(1)}=\frac{2-\frac{1}{2}}{3-2(\frac{1}{2})}=\frac{\frac{3}{2}}{2}=\frac{3}{4}$.

Answer (score 1):

If I get your question correctly, then you can try this:

$$f(x+2) = \frac{x+2} {x+3}$$
$$f(x) = \frac{x} {x+1}$$

$$ x = x.f(x) + f(x)$$ 
$$\implies x(1-f(x)) = f(x)$$

$$\implies x = \frac {f(x)}{1-f(x)}$$

Now substitute this $x$ in $f(x+2)$ and get the desired answer.

Comment: Your sign of $x$ is wrong. That should be $1-f(x)$ instead of $f(x)-1$.

Comment: @tonychow0929 I am sorry, thank you for that :)